# run each input request through a function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Very new to Laravel. Trying to setup a simple contact form to familiarize myself with it. I send the form data via ajax and I process each input with this in javascript:

```
encodeURIComponent($("#contact-name").val())
```

How can I run all of those inputs through

```
urldecode()
```

on the php side without having to manually do each one?

For instance I want to use this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
]);
```

and I can't because the `@` in an email address gets encoded so the validation rule for valid email returns false.

I need to have all the inputs in the request run through `urldecode()` and then get put back so I can use all the convenient stuff Laravel has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just before you $this->validate(... , write following code:

```
foreach($request->all() as $key => $value)
{   
    $request->merge(array( $key => urldecode($value) ));
}
```

above foreach loop will replace **all** input fields with their urldecoded values.

Comment: Excellent solution! I can't believe I missed $request's merge method after sifting through the docs. Thank You!